# I can't fix added height into the component

Tags: javascript, css, sass, material-ui, reactjs

I am working in react.js project using material-ui and sass.I need to create Component like ChatBit component then i wrote it as it published.

customComponent.js file.

```
    // @flow
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import { Avatar} from "@material-ui/core";
    import useStyle from './styles';

    type Props = {
        children: React.Node;
    }

    const AbsoluteBox = ({
        children
    }: Props) => {
        const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
        const styles = useStyle();
        const handleClick = () => {
            setToggled(!toggled);
        };
        const contentStyle = `container__content_${toggled ? 'show': 'hide'}`;
        return (
            <div className={styles.container__bottomRight}>
                <div className={styles.container__header} onClick={handleClick}>
                    <Avatar
                        variant="rounded"
                        src="/assets/images/rebots.svg"
                className={styles.container__header__avatar}
                    />
                </div>
                <div
                    className={styles[contentStyle]}
                >
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default AbsoluteBox;
```

styles.js file.

```
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

    export default makeStyles({
        container__bottomRight: {
            position: 'fixed',
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            marginRight: 12,
            width: 300,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
            borderTopRightRadius: 10,
            boxShadow: '0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.51)'
        },
        container__header: {
            paddingLeft: 10,
            paddingTop: 4,
            paddingBottom: 6,
            backgroundColor: '#D7E0FC',
            height: 38,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
            borderTopRightRadius: 8,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        container__header__avatar: {
            height: 40
        },
        container__content_hide: {
            transition: 'height 400ms 400ms, opacity 400ms 0ms',
            opacity: 0.0,
            height: 0,
        },
        container__content_show: {
            height: 400,
            opacity: 1.0,
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            transition: 'height 400ms 0ms, opacity 400ms 400ms',
        },
    });
```

then i call the Component like that:

```
    <AbsoluteBox>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </AbsoluteBox>
```

so the probleme which i found is when i open the box, everything is correct but when i need to close it, there white space which i don't where is it coming from.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create a live working example (you can do this using https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-shadow-yyw14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h1>` tag that you have inside the box has margin, which cause those issues (the margin is taking place even if the height of the contains is set to 0).

You can fix this by setting the margin-top of the h1 element to 0 (or using some other elements and style them accordingly).